# error in converting html to pdf using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert an HTML document to PDF using `wkhtmltopdf`, using a wrapper from 'knplabs/snappy'. I am getting the following error:

> abcd1234string(95) "vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality 'http://google.com' 'test.pdf'" array(1) { ["some"]=> string(6) "option" } 
>   Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: The exit status code '126' says something went wrong: stderr: "sh: vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64: cannot execute binary file " stdout: "" command: vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality '/var/tmp/knp_snappy58f965265c7ce3.93342883.html' '/tmp/bill-123.pdf'. in /Users/shubhamjoshi/projects/rsvp/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php:336 Stack trace: #0 /Users/shubhamjoshi/projects/rsvp/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php(151): Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator->checkProcessStatus(126, '', 'sh: vendor/h4cc...', 'vendor/h4cc/wkh...') #1 /Users/shubhamjoshi/projects/rsvp/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/Pdf.php(62): Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator->generate(Array, '/tmp/bill-123.p...', Array, false) #2 /Users/shubhamjoshi/projects/rsvp/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php(170): Knp\Snappy\Pdf->generate(Array, '/tmp/bill-123.p...', Array, false) #3 /Users/shubhamjos in /Users/shubhamjoshi/projects/rsvp/vendor/knplabs/knp-snappy/src/Knp/Snappy/AbstractGenerator.php on line 336

This is my php code:

```
<?php
echo ("abcd1234");
array('some' => 'option'));
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Knp\Snappy\Pdf;

// Create a new Pdf object with some global PDF options
$snappy = new Pdf('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-
amd64');

var_dump($snappy->getCommand('http://google.com', 'test.pdf'), 
array('some' => 'option'));

$snappy->generateFromHtml('<h1>Bill</h1><p>You owe me money, dude.
</p>', '/tmp/bill-123.pdf');
?>
```

Please help me resolve this error.

Comment: Please refer to these resources https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-snappy/issues/10

Comment: Error 126 is a permission error in Linux

Comment: how can we solve error 126 for /usr/local/bin/ @mike

Comment: Chmod 755 the script?